# Getting a transparent image from a bmp with alpha

Tags: video

sorry if this sounds a little off topic but it actually has to do with video editing. I made once a logo image as a transparent png to use in virtualdub but since virtualdub logo plugin doesnt allow png I had to convert it to PNG and make an alpha image to use along with it in order to make it look transparent on the video.

Now I need that original image but I lost it and I have only the 2 BMPs. Is there any way to get a transparent png out of those?

Thank you.

Comment: You can do it in Photoshop. See the selected answer here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2231/how-to-create-alpha-mask-from-an-image-in-photoshop-cs-8

Comment: Welcome Cain :) Please start with the tour: http://video.stackexchange.com/tour. First bmp is alpha channel only (black and white) and the second is rgb?

Comment: Both are black and white actually. Its a gray logo with 50% of opacity so one of the BMPs has the logo with a white background whereas the other one has it on a black one.